# SELinux demands constant relabeling

Tags: ubuntu, selinux

I have installed SELinux on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS via

```
# apt install selinux
```

After the mandatory reboot, SELinux was constantly disabled until I added

`SELinux = 1` to `/etc/default/grub`

and executed
`sudo update-grub`

upon which SELinux seems to be working correctly.

`sestatus` reports back with

```
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             default
Current mode:                   permissive
Mode from config file:          permissive
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
Memory protection checking:     requested (insecure)
Max kernel policy version:      31
```

However, executing

```
# sudo systemctl status selinux
```

yields

```
Nov 21 14:38:51 ubuntu-selinux systemd[1]: 
Started LSB: Relabel the filesystem before reboot.
```

even though I have relabeled the file-system by adding `touch /.autorelabel` and also executing `sudo fixfiles relabel` and rebooting the system afterwards.

Additional information that may be relevant

- apparmor was successfully removed
- filesystem is `ext4`
- This is a fresh install, so nothing else was tinkered with.

My question(s): Why did I have to add the kernel parameter manually and why is SELinux prompting me for another relabel on every boot?

Comment: Ubuntu does not fully support selinux policy so you have to write your own. If you want selinux use fedora / RHEL / Centos

Answer (score 0):

Don't install the `selinux` package, install `selinux-basic` instead.

The `selinux` package is ubuntu specific and is really old and not working well with systemd.

To be honest I thought it was already removed from the ubuntu archive for a while.

Answer (score 0):

You had to manually add the kernel parameters because Ubuntu uses AppArmor by default and it's kinda rare to see SELinux used on ubuntu systems. That might actually be considered a bug, and you might want to consider opening a launchpad bug report for the selinux package.

Regarding the constant relabeling: does the `/.autorelabel` file still exist after a reboot ? On CentOS/RHEL one of the systemd units removes it AFAIK, but this might not happen on Ubuntu I guess.